# Illegal start of a expression JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

```
constant.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
        min = sNum.chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray();
                                  ^
1 error
```

I uploaded my code to a page where it gives you a problem and you upload it and checks that it does what it should.

I'm using Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1 and gives me no error but the page gives me this error.

I'm new in JAVA and I do not fully understand it. Could someone explain me why this is happening and how could I fix this?

My code pretty much starts like this, it just asks for a number then calls a function that does this to put the number entered to array.

Comment: This code is completely fine. This might be casued by inproper language version setting in your IDE. Go to your project settings and set language level to 1.8 or higher

Comment: or maybe the problem is in "a page"s settings... but no idea what page this is (what else to expect when speaking of [Jane Doe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe) [:-) )

Comment: What page are you talking about? Please specify it in your question. Then either you or someone else can post an actual solution to the problem, which is how to modify Java version on that page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is completely fine. You should change your language settings in your IDE. Your language level must be set below 8 and therefor the old compiler doesn't understand lambdas.